# nested exception is javax.persistence

Tags: spring, hibernate, bean-validation

I/m novice at JPA and Hibernate. Whem i/m tryin' to code SAVE method I recieve this error:

> springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not
>   commit JPA transaction; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the
>   transaction

Code:

```
@PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserMeal save(UserMeal userMeal, int userId) {
        User ref = em.getReference(User.class, userId);
        userMeal.setUser(ref);

        if (userMeal.isNew()) {
            em.persist(userMeal);
            return userMeal;
        } else {
            if (get(userMeal.getId(), userId) == null) return null;
            return em.merge(userMeal);
        }    }
```

Comment: Read, and post, the **complete** stack trace to know why you got a rollback.

Comment: i found the reason : 

 No validator could be found for constraint "'javax.validation.constraints.Size' validating type 'java.time.LocalDateTime' "


 what should i do?

Comment: so nothing to do with JPA then, and everything to do with the Bean Validation API (javax.validation)

Comment: Remove the Size annotation on that LocalDateTime field?

Comment: i've done this, now it's works
[`code
@NotNull
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
protected LocalDateTime dateTime;`]